# cakephp illegal offset string in php 5.4

Tags: string, cakephp

MyHtmlHelper

```
public function url($url = null, $full = false) { 
        if(empty($url['lang']) && isset($this->params['lang'])) {
          $url['lang'] = $this->params['lang'];
        } 
        return parent::url($url, $full); 
   }
```

AppHelper

```
public function url($url = null, $full = false) {

        if (empty($url['lang'])) {
            $url['lang'] = $this->params['lang'];
        }
        return parent::url($url, $full);


    }
```

when I ran . application warnings cakephp illegal offset lang .....
how do I fix that errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the values you test are actually set first.

Change this:

```
if(empty($url['lang']) && isset($this->params['lang'])) {
    $url['lang'] = $this->params['lang'];
}
```

To:

```
if ( ( ! isset( $url['lang'] ) || empty( $url['lang'] ) ) && isset( $this->params['lang'] ) ) {
    $url['lang'] = $this->params['lang'];
}
```

I'm not sure whether I have this the right way round for what you're trying to achieve by the way. In my example I'm checking if the value of $url['lang'] is either not set or empty. It may be that you want to check that it is set and empty.

Use the same technique on the AppHelper as well to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add is_array($url) to your validation.
Or you might get  “Illegal string offset ‘language'”

```
function url($url = null, $full = false) {

    if(!isset($url['language']) && is_array($url) && isset($this->params['language']))
    {
        $url['language'] = $this->params['language'];
    }

    return parent::url($url, $full);
}
```